# Is there a way to collect all the files a blend file is using?

Tags: workflow

Is there a way blender can sort of collect all the files that is uses within a session. Because I need to tidy the files on my computer but some of them will have paths to blender session and some won't?

Answer (score 4):

You could *Pack* all the files being used into the blend file and then *Unpack* all the files into a new location.

*Packing* saves any external files that are in use into the blend file itself (but this doesn't remove the originals from the hard drive). *Unpacking* will save the currently packed files out into directory of the current blend file (a few other options are available), thus 'collecting' all the files.

1. *File> External Data> Pack All Into .blend*.
2. Save the file.
3. *File> External Data> Unpack All Into Files> Write files to current directory*.
4. Save the file.

So, you can essentially 'collect' all the files in use into one location, but you can't actually get the original files to move (using this method).

Comment: Just keep in mind that video files and image sequences are not packed into the file, Simulations cache or Dyniamic paint one are not packed either. An alternative to "contain" all of the files used in  aproject, is to put them all in the same folder as the .blend file and use ["relative paths"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/files/relative_paths.html), then just compress the whole folder as a .zip file.